# Defining function name as dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have one dynamic elements and functionality in my site.
The every dynamically generated element has different functionality but i has same function name of all elements. I have the problem to replaced the value inside the callback function.

So I need to define the function name as dynamic.

I dont know it's possible or not in javascript/jquery.
:

```
var count= 1;

...
...

  function test+count() { // Here count will be replacing the value of count variable

    ...
    ...
  }


...
...
count++;
...
...
```

This is my needs.

Is there any possibilities/other ways to fulfill this needs?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: what do you want to achieve? it sounds like mistery and I'm pretty sure that you try to do it the hard and inappropriate way

Comment: `window[test+count()]()`

Comment: Yes, there are ways to do this. Search for "variable variables in Javascript". **BUT** this sounds like a really bad idea. There's gotta be a better solution, but it's unclear what your context is here.

Comment: can't you have a function test() that receives the count number and that is the same for all and then use an if else inside the function?

Comment: There's no way to use dynamic identifiers in function declarations. But I'm quite sure that is [not your actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - for which a solution likely exists.

Comment: Please describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than this very odd requirement for dynamic functions (that presumably all do the same thing anyway).

Comment: Thanks for your response all. I know this is not possible. I need to generate the function name as dynamic.

Comment: No, you do not need to, you can easily use a closure. But if you don't tell us about the problem, we cannot present you a fitting solution.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your idea to use closure. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Definition

```
function name() {}
```

is equal to

```
window.name = function() {}
```

and to

```
window['name'] = function() {}
```

and to

```
var function_name = 'na' + 'me';
window[function_name] = function() {}
```

This should answer your question.

Comment: [No it's not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname), [really not](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/). And `window` properties are always global, which you shouldn't do as well.

Comment: @Radek Thanks for your response and time. I update and check this way.

Comment: @shijin: "Working" does not mean "the answer is correct". That the declaration was equal to the assignment is definitely not true.

Comment: @Bergi I just check his example :)

Comment: @Bergi For most intends and purposes they're pretty much equal in the given context. Yes, there are differences, but the gist of the answer is a solution to the problem as posed.

Comment: It equals in a way how you should use it. If you depend on fact that you can call method before you define it, you should probably consider doing something else than programming ;).

Answer (score 2):

Instead of bunch of similar functions with different names you can define a single one which would change its behavior depending on passed `count` parameter:

```
function test(count) {
    // alter behavior depending on count value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

**Definition**

```
var count=1;
for(;count<5;count++)
{   
var name="test_name"+count;
window[name] = new Function('alert( "Inside '+name+'")');
}
```

**Call it dynamically**

```
for(count=1;count<5;count++)
{   
 window["test_name" + count]();
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sfBK8/15/)

Comment: Aside from syntax change, how is this different from the previous  `window[name] = function() {alert("hello world");}` style answers?